# How to use VisualStudio build configuration to define DEBUG for dotnet Core project?

Tags: c#, .net-core

As far as I know, `Debug.Assert` will not work without `"define": [ "DEBUG" ]` in project.json. I want to have it on dev machine and strip out on build server. 
Should I just modify project.json as txt file after checkout on build server, or there is more elegant way?

PS. I know about "project.json in 2017".

Comment: You mean the DEBUG constant also found in the project settings > create > define DEBUG constant?

Answer (score 3):

You can define different options for different configurations in [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/home/wiki/project.json-file). On your build server you can build the "Release" configuration.

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "Debug": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": ["DEBUG", "TRACE"]
      }
    },
    "Release": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": ["RELEASE", "TRACE"],
        "optimize": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for link. However I notice that Debug.Assert work _without_ any `define`. And after defining nothing changed in Properties>Build>General.

Comment: See my edit. It looks like Microsoft updated it to `buildOptions` rather than `compilationOptions`.

Comment: Yes, I typed so, but anyway - `"DEBUG"` seems to be default define for Debug config, and project properties page assumes only `define` in top-level `buildOptions`. So question does not need answer.